# D3js v4. How to determine custom event?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to remove svg elements by custom "click + delete" event. I know how to determine click event, and events like ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey. But I want to use other keys. What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to listen to two different events to achieve this, notably `keydown` and `keyup` events. Let's pretend we've got a circle:

```
const DELETE_KEYCODE = 46;
let deletePressed = false;

d3.select("svg")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .on("keydown", () => { deletePressed = d3.event.keyCode === DELETE_KEYCODE; })
  .on("keyup", () => { deletePressed = false; })
  .on("click", (d, i, elements) => {
      if (deletePressed) {
         d3.select(elements[i]).remove();
      }
  });
```

Now realistically you probably want `keyup` to be a bit more intelligent, in case they pressed several keys and didn't `keyup` the <kbd>delete</kbd>! But I'll let you work that bit out.

Comment: I don't know why, but "keydown" and "keyup" work only for html elements. I have moved them to d3.select("body") and it works. Thx for the idea.